# elasticsearch fails VerifyRepositoryRequest in C# Nest client

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

After updating to elasticsearch 7.5.1 following code is now causing an exception
"Entry point not found"

```
//old code worked just fine
    var verifyRepositoryResponse = this.elasticClient.VerifyRepository(new VerifyRepositoryRequest("C__MYFOLDER_Backup"));

//new code throws

    var verifyRepositoryResponse = this.elasticClient.Snapshot.VerifyRepository(new VerifyRepositoryRequest("C__MYFOLDER_Backup"));
```

Note that making following request via fiddler

```
POST http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/C__MYFOLDER_Backup/_verify HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:9200
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
```

returns

```
{"nodes":{"1cWG9trDRi--6I-46lOlBw":{"name":"DESKTOP-5L01F6I"}}}
```

any ideas what causes the problem here?
Unfortunately there is zero documentation on that matter.

**UPDATE**:
Calling the code with a non existing directory as argument

```
var verifyRepositoryResponse = this.elasticClient.Snapshot.VerifyRepository(new VerifyRepositoryRequest("C__DOESNOTEXIST_Backup"));
```

I will get a 4xx response as expected in this scenario.
Before all tests, repositories and db have been cleaned.

**Update**:
Adavanced error information:

```
"# FailureReason: Unrecoverable/Unexpected BadResponse while attempting POST on http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/C__MYFOLDER_Backup/_verify\r\n - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Exception: EntryPointNotFoundException Took: 00:00:00.1859931\r\n# Audit 
exception in step 1 BadResponse:\r\nSystem.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.IJsonFormatter`1.Deserialize(JsonReader& reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)\r\n   at Deserialize(Object[] , 
JsonReader& , IJsonFormatterResolver )\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream, 
IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.DiagnosticsSerializerProxy.Deserialize[T](Stream stream)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.SetBody[TResponse](ApiCallDetails details, RequestData requestData, Stream responseStream, String 
mimeType)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.ToResponse[TResponse](RequestData requestData, Exception ex, Nullable`1 statusCode, IEnumerable`1 warnings, Stream responseStream, String mimeType)\r\n   at 
Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, 
String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)\r\n# Inner Exception: Entry point was not found.\r\nSystem.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.IJsonFormatter`1.Deserialize(JsonReader& 
reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)\r\n   at Deserialize(Object[] , JsonReader& , IJsonFormatterResolver )\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)\r\n   at 
Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream, IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.DiagnosticsSerializerProxy.Deserialize[T](Stream stream)\r\n   at 
Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.SetBody[TResponse](ApiCallDetails details, RequestData requestData, Stream responseStream, String mimeType)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.ToResponse[TResponse](RequestData requestData, Exception ex, Nullable`1 
statusCode, IEnumerable`1 warnings, Stream responseStream, String mimeType)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData 
requestData)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)\r\n# Exception:\r\nElasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: Entry point was not found. ---> 
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.IJsonFormatter`1.Deserialize(JsonReader& reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)\r\n   at Deserialize(Object[] , JsonReader& , IJsonFormatterResolver 
)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream, IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)\r\n   at 
Elasticsearch.Net.DiagnosticsSerializerProxy.Deserialize[T](Stream stream)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.SetBody[TResponse](ApiCallDetails details, RequestData requestData, Stream responseStream, String mimeType)\r\n   at 
Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.ToResponse[TResponse](RequestData requestData, Exception ex, Nullable`1 statusCode, IEnumerable`1 warnings, Stream responseStream, String mimeType)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData 
requestData)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)\r\n   --- 
End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)\r\n   at 
Nest.Specification.SnapshotApi.SnapshotNamespace.VerifyRepository(IVerifyRepositoryRequest request)\r\n   at InforsHT.Genesis.Infrastructure.Data.Repositories.ElasticBackupAndRestoreProxy.IsBackupLocationPresent(String backupLocation) in 
C:\\work\\eve\\Source\\InforsHT.Genesis.Infrastructure.Data\\Repositories\\ElasticBackupAndRestoreProxy.cs:line 44\r\n"
```

Comment: Sounds like Elasticsearch.Net dependency might be the older version still - try updating Elasticsearch.Net to the same version. What version did you upgrade from? What version of .NET framework/core are you running?

Comment: I did update via NuGet Package manager. Previous version was 5.2. I am running .NET Framework 7.4.2. Note that all other code (same reference to Elastic.NET) is running fine

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean .NET Framework 4.7.2? Are there any other environment details you think might be pertinent?

Comment: Yes sure I ment 4.7.2 of course. No I would not know about anything other pertinent besides what I updated just now.

Comment: Ok. so `"Entry point not found"` happens when the directory exists on disk, but a 404 response is returned when the directory does not exist? Do you get an exception/stack trace when the exception happens? If so, can you include it in the question? If you don't get one in the app, there may be one in Application events in Event viewer if on Windows.

Comment: I just added exception details: http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/C__MYFOLDER_Backup/_verify\r\n ---> this could be the issue right? what is the '\r\n' doing here? Input parameter was 'C__MYFOLDER_Backup'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. `VerifyRepositoryResponse`'s `Node` property is attributed with a `JsonFormatterAttribute` that expects to deserialize an `IDictionary<string, CompactNodeInfo>` when the property type is `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, CompactNodeInfo>`. This is problematic for the underlying JSON serializer which uses strongly typed formatters, `IJsonFormatter<T>`, where the type `T` must match exactly.

I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/4382) to track and [a pull request to fix](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/4383) the issue. For now, you'd be able to workaround the bug by using the low level client exposed on the high level client

```
var response = client.LowLevel.Snapshot.VerifyRepository<DynamicResponse>("C__MYFOLDER_Backup");
```

and traverse `DynamicResponse`. Alternatively, use `StringResponse` and parse using `JObject` or `JsonDocument` and traverse.

Comment: Okay fine thanks! I'll let you know if it's working!

Comment: Now I get a 404 back but ApiCall.Success is true. BUT: Providing a non existing repositoryname will result in the exact (?) same response?

Comment: Note that DynamicDictionary for both valid and invalid repositories always contains errors: System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>
  Key "type" string
  Value "repository_missing_exception" object {string}
+  Non-Public members  
-  [2] {[reason, [C:\MYFOLDER\Backup] missing]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>
  Key "reason" string
  Value "[C:\\MYFOLDER\\Backup] missing" object {string}

Comment: Can you use `StringResponse`, and edit your question to add the response JSON for a repository you believe exists?

Comment: Actually I passed a wrong argument (copy paste issue) for low level client version. Now it works as expected!

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: by the way: same problem occurs for elasticClient.Indices.Exists(index)